# Python3.8 Multiprocess Keyboard/Mouse Listeners not being persistent

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

So, I've been trying to learn Python multiprocessing ,done a bunch of tutorials , and decided to revisit some of my old apps and implement the new found knowledge, but got stuck on a listener/print code

There's no error code whatsoever and the terminal doesn't wait any signal from the processes,
can't get any print feedback, don't know what to do !

Main code:

```
import time
import multiprocessing
from Keyboard_Listener import *
from Mouse_Listener import *

def process_Keyboard_Listener():
    kbl = KeyBoard_Listener()
    kbl.start_up()

def process_Mouse_Listener():
    ml = Mouse_Listener()
    ml.start_up()

process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_Keyboard_Listener)
process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_Mouse_Listener)

process1.start()
process2.start()

process1.join()
process2.join()
```

Both Classes:

```
from pynput import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key

class KeyBoard_Listener:

def __init__(self):
    self.listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_press,on_release=self.on_release)

def __enter__(self):
    self.listener.start()

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    self.listener.stop()

def on_press(self,key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(key))

def on_release(self,key):
    print('{0} release'.format(key))


def start_up(self):
    self.listener.start()
    print("started Keyboard")
```

---

```
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.mouse import Listener

class Mouse_Listener:


def __init__(self):
        self.listener=mouse.Listener(on_move=self.on_move,on_click=self.on_click,on_scroll=self.on_scroll)

def __enter__(self):
    self.listener.start()

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    self.listener.stop()


def on_move(self,x, y):
    print('Pointer moved to {0}'.format((x, y)))

def on_click(self,x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format('Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',(x, y)))

def on_scroll(self,x, y, dx, dy):
    print('Scrolled {0} at {1}'.format('down' if dy < 0 else 'up',(x, y)))

def start_up(self):
    self.listener.start()
    print("started Mouse")
```

Thanks for reading !